# Asking for reference for challenging problems for Functional Analysis 1st course

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am a masters 1st year student and my functional analysis course ended 1 week ago. The instructor followed  Irwin Krieszig's Book " Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications" for teaching and although he didn't gave any assignments or exercise problems, I solved problems from exercises given in Krieszig's Book. I was able to understand the concepts given in the book clearly and then do exercises of Krieszig without much difficulty. But I noticed that the problems of the book are  much easier for a masters student but as I was busy in some extra - curricular activities also , so I didn't tried other problems or asked for reference books or materials here.

But Now I think that I must solve good number of Challenging problems in Functional Analysis as I will apply for phd in pure mathematics soon and I got my December break time to it.

> So, Can you please tell any book in functional analysis course whose exercises are challenging as compared to Krieszig's  / any assignments which any professor of a university gave which are available on web?

Also, I am adding my course syllabus in the following images so that you come to know exactly which topics should be  available( I absolutely no problem If more topics are covered). All these topics were covered which are given in the images and none except them were covered.

Edit: I am good in measure theory , so if any functional analysis book you are recommending assumes knowledge of measure theory  then I am fine with it.

[image]

[image]

Looking for your help.

Comment: A nice book on [Real Analysis](https://measure.axler.net/) by Sheldon Axler] (It has chapters on functional analysis also) is available free online.

Comment: Take a look to Exercises in analysis (Part I) by Leszek Gasiński, & Nikolaos S Papageorgiou and also Exercises in Functional Analysis by Constantin Costara & Dumitru Popa. They have solutions and good summary of contents.

Comment: A "challenging" book is Dunford and Schwartz. But I wouldn't read it.

Comment: @s.harp why you wouldn't read it?

Comment: @Ben: I appreciate Kreyszig's book, it's a nice and highly readable classic. But note that Kreyszig *explicitely* excludes measure theory. If you are not comfortable with measure theory you might have difficulties, since many functional analysis books assume a basic knowledge of measure theory as prerequisite. You might want to address this aspect in your question to get appropriate book recommendations.

Comment: You may look at "A Hilbert space problem book" by Paul R. Halmos.

Comment: @Ben because its 3000 pages long

Comment: @s.harp Ok, thanks for telling.

Comment: @MarkusScheuer  Ok, I have edited my question to mention that I have already done a course on measure theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may follow the following references:

$1.~~$ "Theorems and Problems in Functional Analysis" by A. A. Kirillov, A. D. Gvishiani 
$2.~~$ "Problems in Real and Functional Analysis" by Alberto Torchinsky 
$3.~~$ "Theorems and Problems in Functional Analysis" by J. D. Knowles 
$4.~~$ "A Glimpse at Hilbert Space Operators" by Paul R. Halmos

These books contains many standard problems. Most of the problems are hard but very good once it is done. I think you may get benefit from here so just try it.

Answer (score 3):

I'll recommend [Exercises in Analysis, Part I](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319061757) by Gasiński, and Papageorgiou. It's a brilliant source of thoughtful and challenging exercises in mathematical analysis; starting from basics of metrics spaces, then topology, measure theory and functional analysis. Also, it comes with full solutions.

For more advanced topics there's also a second part too by the same authors.